# How to set conditional breakpoint if malloc returns NULL via gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb, malloc

#### Sample source code:

```
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <stdlib.h>
#include        <errno.h>

#define         GIGABYTE        1024*1024*1024

int
main (void)
{
        void    *foo;
        int     result;

        foo = (void *) malloc (GIGABYTE*5);
        result = errno;

        if (foo != NULL) {
                return 2;
        } else {
                fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: %d\n", result);
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

#### Question:

- How to instruct gdb (`# gdb -silent ./huge_malloc`) to **stop/halt** execution, if `malloc()` returns `0x0`, **without** checking if `foo` is `0x0`

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do (and especially why you're making the distinction between the return value of `malloc` and the resulting value of `foo`).

Comment: Simply, 'break' whenever malloc() returns NULL - the source above, is just an example. The variable name (in this case foo), might be named otherwise.

Comment: As a work-around, maybe you could break on `malloc()`, then use a command list to first exit `malloc()` and then conditionally continue if `$eax != 0`?

Comment: @Georg: How to accomplish this via gdb?

Comment: Just an idea as i haven't tried it, but take a look [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could identify the exit point of malloc and put a conditional breakpoint there. Such as:

```
(gdb) tbreak main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005c4: file t.c, line 13.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /var/tmp/a.out 
main () at t.c:13
13          foo = malloc (64);
(gdb) br *__libc_malloc+211 if $rax==0
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7f26d143ea93
(gdb) n
14          foo = malloc (GIGABYTE*64);
(gdb) p foo
$1 = (void *) 0x21dc010
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 2, 0x00007f26d143ea93 in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Note, I have added a `malloc` call that succeeds first, to illustrate that the breakpoint only triggers for a `NULL` return value. The breakpoint address may vary with libc versions, I found it by stepping through `malloc` with `nexti` until I hit the `ret` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just write a wrapper around `malloc` that saves the return value and then set a conditional breakpoint on that value?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible. The source above is just an example - I cannot change the source.

Comment: @Aaron: But you could define `malloc` to `mymalloc` (using `-D`), force the include of the necessary header for all source files, ... ?

Comment: @Aaron: GNU ld has a `-wrap` flag that can be useful for this sort of thing, does not require recompilation of other source files to accommodate the wrapper